# Why does R Markdown change code block font? How can I change it back to a monospace font?"

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to create an R markdown file, but whenever I go to knit the document, the code blocks are created with Times New Roman. How can I change it back to the default monospace font?

For context, I'm working in R Studio with knitr and I am not changing any of the settings for the code block in the script.

Comment: Please give us a screenshot of the knitted document. Just with example data...

Comment: Not just a screenshot, please include the source of a document in your question.

Comment: This my be helpful: https://gist.github.com/richarddmorey/27e74bcbf28190d150d266ae141f5117

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.